# Use separate faces as instances in geometry nodes? (Blender 3.*)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a mesh where each face is separated from each other. I'd like to add some motion to the faces by their vectors, but if I bring this object to geometry nodes I get only one instance imported (a whole object itself). Is there any way to use this object as a bunch of instances so I could affect faces separately from each other?
[image](the cube is just an example)

Comment: How did you import this object to GN? as single object or as collection?

Comment: A single object. With collections the solution is simple. But I’m trying to achieve  non-destructive pipeline so I need the mesh as one object here.

Comment: Ah, Ok, apologies.  My answer had a collection as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This setup shows basic transformation based on its face center.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Dang! The position node should have it been >0< I tried to achieve this with the mesh island and normal nodes all this time T_T 
Thanks! =)

Comment: Using this technique, would it be possible to have them only rotate from the bottom edge for example, or would you need to have them as separate instances?